# Logstash mutate filter gsub nested field

Tags: regex, filter, logstash, gsub

I am trying to filter some e-mails in logstash before sending it to ES.

I have one field still containing e-mail adresses and can't gsub it by mutate filter.

```
mutate {
    gsub => [
        "log", "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", "--- FILTERED FROM LOGS ---",
        "message", "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", "--- FILTERED FROM LOGS ---"
            ]
        }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "_index": "logs-2021.03.09.11",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "sdfsdf",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "source": "stderr",
    "@timestamp": "2021-03-09T11:39:38.413Z",
    "kubernetes": {
      "namespace": "sdfsdk",
      "labels": {
        "pod-template-hash": "sdfsdf",
        "app": {
          "softwear": {
            "co/name": "sdfsd",
            "co/domain": "sdfsdf"
          }
        },
    "log": {
      "extra_fields": {
        "ctxt_response": "{\"records_id\":[{\"ext_id\":\"sdfsdf\",\"fcc_id\":sdfsdfsd,\"external_id\":\"sdfsdf\"}],\"success\":true}",
        "requestDevice": "\"\"",
        "ctxt_request": "{\"hash\":\"56kdfhsdfjshdkf\",\"change\":\"sdsd\",\"campaigns_id\":114,\"method\":\"sha1\",\"login\":\"test\",\"records\":[{\"emails\":[\"email-to-delete@gmail.com\"],\"external_id\":\"sdsdK\"}]}",
        "ctxt_response_code": "200"
      },
```

How can I get nested field and gsub it? [log][extra_fields][ctxt_request]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```rb
mutate {
    gsub => [
        "[log][extra_fields][ctxt_request]", "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", "--- FILTERED FROM LOGS ---",
        "message", "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", "--- FILTERED FROM LOGS ---"
    ]
}
```

I also noticed a possible improvement in your regex:

- `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]`

- `[A-Za-z0-9\._%+-]` (escape the dot `.` character - you'll need to do this on both sides of the `@`)

You might also want to look at using the [JSON Filter Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) to parse the `ctxt_request` field - then you could just overwrite the contents of that one subfield without using `gsub` at all.

Here's an example of how that might work. Caveats are a) that it hasn't been tested, b) that doing the `remove_field` on the `JSON` output might not work (although removing the source field will work if the `JSON` was successfully parsed), and c) that you might have other ideas for how you structure the fields.

```rb
json {
    source => "[log][extra_fields][ctxt_request]"
    target => "[log][extra_fields][parsed][ctxt_request]"
    remove_field => [
        "[log][extra_fields][ctxt_request]",
        # remove the field completely
        "[log][extra_fields][parsed][ctxt_request][records][emails]"
    ]
}
mutate {
    # or replace it with the text from your question
    replace => {
        "[log][extra_fields][parsed][ctxt_request][records][emails]" =>
        "--- FILTERED FROM LOGS ---"
    }
}
```